# Need a `values_at_if ` method to map values in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays of the same size

```
response = ["N","N","Y","Y","Y"]
mapping = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

I need to select the elements in `mapping` whose corresponding value in `response`, i.e., the element with the same index, is `"Y"`, as below

```
["C","D","E"]
```

It reminds me of the `values_at` method. My solution is as follows

```
def values_at_if(response, mapping)
    result=[]
     response.each_index |k|
       if k=="Y"
         result << mapping[k]
       end
     end
   result
end
```

I am not happy with it. Please let me know of a way to do it efficiently.

Comment: Please share why a down vote, I am new.

Comment: Smart, interesting, better, happy — all emotive and opinion based terms. Do you have a _programming_ issue? Your code works, it isn’t inefficient, lots of people would write it that way, it is clear, so what’s the trouble?

Comment: I can understand why you are not happy with your code: it contains three errors! :-). You need to add `do` before `|k|` in `response.each_index |k|` and in if `k="Y"` `k` should be `response[k]` and `=` should be `==`. Aside from that your approach is fine. More Ruby-like would be to write `response.each_index.with_object([]) do |k,result|`, which would allow you to remove `result = []` and `result` at the end. Lastly, some (me included) would write `result << mapping[k] if result[k] == 'Y'`, reducing three lines to one.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

The simplest solution I can come up with is:

```
mapping.select.with_index {|_,i| response[i] == "Y"}
#=>["C", "D", "E"]
```

This will `select` all the elements in `mapping` where the corresponding index in `response` equals `"Y"`

**TL;DR Other options include:**

```
mapping.values_at(*response.each_with_index.select {|v,_| v == "Y"}.map(&:last))


mapping.zip(response).map {|k,v| k if v == "Y"}.compact
```

The first uses each with index which will be

```
[["N",0],["N",1],["Y",2],["Y",3],["Y",4]]
```

then we select the groups where the first element is "Y" and map the indexes to pass to `values_at`

The second version zips the mapping and the response together creating.

```
[["A", "N"], ["B", "N"], ["C", "Y"], ["D", "Y"], ["E", "Y"]]
```

Then map the first element only when the second element is "Y". the compact removes the `nil` values from the mapping.

There are a lot of other ways to accomplish this task if you have a look through the `Enumerable` module

Comment: which do you recommend? and why?

Comment: @Lefty I recommend whichever feels more natural to you even if it isn't one of the above solutions. In this case the data set is inconsequentially small and thus performance factors will have no impact.

Comment: ...or (#1) `...values_at(*response.each_index.select {|i| response[i] == "Y"})`.

Comment: Re #2 I believe you need to tack on `.map(&:last)`. `each_with_index` may be a better choice to avoid `compact` (a really ugly method, imo) and `.map(&:last)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no need for `map(&:last)` as I am only mapping the first element. however I think `mapping.select.with_index {|_,i| response[i] == "Y"}` is a far better solution as it result in the creation of only 1 array

Comment: Ah, yes. I agree that `select.with_index` is better, so why not give that in your answer?

Comment: I like mapping.select.with_index {|_,i| response[i] == "Y"}, it seems clean and understandable, this is what I was thinking existed, just did not know how to do.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with

```
mapping.zip(response).select { |_, r| r == 'Y' }.map(&:first)
#=> ["C", "D", "E"]
```

Comment: Is it more efficient usage of memory or speed?

Comment: @Lefty Use [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to gain some insight. If you're really concerned about speed, avoid using strings here for the masking and instead have an array of the form `[false, false, true, true, true]`.

Comment: @Lefty For small arrays with only a couple of hundreds of elements, I would not care too much about speed or memory consumption. In such contexts, readability and being easy to understand is much more important. How big are your `mapping` and `response` arrays? Do you have the option to control them or do you get them from an external source?

Answer (score 3):

Convert `response` to an Enumerator; `each` without a block does that. Then use it in the select block. If the block returns `true` then the item is selected:

```
response = ["N","N","Y","Y","Y"]
mapping  = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

enum_resp = response.each
mapping.select{ enum_resp.next == "Y" } # =>["C", "D", "E"]
```

Note it would save memory if `response` would consist of `false` and `true`s, which also would make the comparison in the select block unnecessary.

Comment: you could have used `to_enum` rather than `each`, that would be more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(v, arr), i|
  arr << mapping[i] if v == 'Y' 
end
```

Or

```
mapping.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(v, arr), i|
  arr << v if response[i] == 'Y' 
end
```